# How to make an Alert Dialog "Rate my game" for my game

Tags: andengine

I wonder if anyone can help me on how to make an alert dialog which makes user rate the game from inside the game itself or taking the user to google play to rate. Please help. I'm using andengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for. It shouldn't matter that you are using andengine. Its all the same =-)

http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater.html

Comment: the link you attached is not working.

Comment: Looks like they changed the url a tiny bit. This was a few years ago so this post may not be as relevant =-) http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater.html